# How to find file with specific word in name in cakephp 2.3.x?

Tags: cakephp, directory

I want to read files with specific word in name from a folder.
for eg., I have three files in a folder named, `1.jpg, 1_1.jpg, 150x150_1.jpg`

I want to retrive files with name like "_1.jpg" or "1.jpg" from a folder using cakephp.
How can I do it ?

Is there any other way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Folder::find()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/file-folder.html#Folder%3a%3afind) method with a regular expression.

```
$dir = new Folder(WWW_ROOT . 'img');
$files = $dir->find('(.*_1.jpg|1.jpg)', true);
debug($files);
```

Comment: can you give regex for condition I have provided ?

Comment: Done. It will look for all files ending with `_1.jpg` or named `1.jpg`